# Fastest and cheapest way in AWS to redirect one domain to another

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, aws-amplify, amazon-route53

Suppose I have a hosted zone named `here.com` in Route53 and I want my users to be redirected to `there.com` according to the following rules:

- `here.com` redirects to `there.com`
- `here.com/*` redirects to `there.com/*`, *e.g.* `here.com/qwerty` redirects to `there.com/qwerty`
- `www.here.com` redirects to `there.com`
- `www.here.com/*` redirects to `there.com/*`, *e.g.* `www.here.com/qwerty` redirects to `there.com/qwerty`

There seems to be a number of ways of creating redirects in the AWS ecosystem. Here are some of the ways I found:

1. Use [S3 static web host redirect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-page-redirect.html)
2. Use [S3 static web host redirect + CloudFront distribution](https://nelson.cloud/redirect-one-domain-to-another-using-aws-s3-and-cloudfront/)
3. Use [Amplify redirect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html)
4. Use [CloudFront function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/example-function-redirect-url.html)
5. Use [Lambda@Edge function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html#lambda-examples-http-redirect)
6. Any other?

Given that, what would be the cheapest way to create the desired redirects in terms of monthly AWS cost?

And what would be the fastest way in terms of user response time?

Comment: yes, all the above ways work, but issue with https can be resolved with the 1 and 2 only. Using Route53 CNAME feature also will not help in the https issue.

Comment: How is `there.com` hosted? If it is behind an Application Load Balancer already, you could point `here.com` to the same load balancer, and configure rules in the load balancer that would handle the redirects for no extra charge. Otherwise, option 2 is probably the cheapest version that will support SSL.

Comment: @MarkB `there.com` is hosted outside AWS. I guess option 2 is the way to go then. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, unless wherever `there.com` is hosted has some redirect options. You could even configure the redirects directly in the web server software (nginx, apache, etc.) hosting `there.com` depending on what sort of web server that is.

Comment: @MarkB unfortunately I don't have access to `there.com` server, it's a third-party service :(

Answer (score 1):

Just go to Route 53 and:

- Create a CNAME record for `here.com` that points to `there.com`
- Create a CNAME for `www.here.com` that points to `www.there.com`

Comment: I believe that would be domain mapping, not redirection. According to [AWS repost](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/route-53-redirect-to-another-domain): Domain mapping: When you map a domain using a CNAME record, the domain name stays the same when you enter the URL in a browser. For example, if you use a CNAME record to map "www.example.com" to "www.example.net", then the URL remains http://www.example.com.